# AutoHotKey CapsLock conditon the activation of the script

Tags: autohotkey

In AutoHotKey (AHK) I wanted to just condition my script.

If caps lock his OFF nothing happen if it's ON the script his executed and of course detect any change

here is my try but won't work it allow the script to be executed caps lock ON or OFF :

```
#Requires AutoHotKey v2.0
state := GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
if(state = 1)
{
LAlt & i::Send "{Up}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#combo) says:

> Note: For **combinations with standard modifier keys**, it is usually
> better to **use the standard syntax**. For example, use **<+s::** rather than
> LShift & s::.

In this case:

```
#Requires AutoHotKey v2.0

; LAlt + I
<!i::Send "{Up}"
```

**<!** is the symbol for the left Alt key.

See [**Hotkey Modifier Symbols**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols)

To **make Hotkeys or Hotstrings context-sensitive**, use the [**#HotIf** directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/_HotIf.htm):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#HotIf GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")

    <!i::Send "{Up}"
    <!k::Send "{Down}"

#HotIf  ; turn off context sensitivity
```

Answer (score 0):

[#Requires](https://ahkscript.github.io/ko/docs/lib/_Requires.htm)
only checks the AutoHotKey version.

Use code such as :

```
GetKeyState, CapLck, CapsLock, T
if ( CapLck == "D" ) {          ; check key-down condition
  some statement
}
```

Comment: first thanks for your answer
When I add a statement 
LAlt & i::Send "{Up}"

its work what ever the caps lock status on or off ...

Comment: GetKeyState, CapLck, CapsLock, T
if ( CapLck == "D" ) {          ; check key-down condition
LAlt & i::Send "{Up}"
}

Comment: You need to make it: ` LAlt & i::GetKeyState etc.`. The trigger need to *contain* the entire code.